# Passing exec command with php variable

Tags: php, shell, unix, exec, shell-exec

I have searched and searched for an answer for this but everything referenced did not have any helpful information regarding my problem. I am trying to send a kill signal to a process I have in order to make the channel skip the current song. The command that needs to be run is: 
kill -10 PID

Please note: $pid2 (below) will hold the true value of the process ID

You can see what I have already:

```
$pid1 = explode(" ", $pid[0]);
$pid2 = $pid1[3];
$next = shell_exec("kill -10" . "$pid2");
```

This is what I have found to be the solution, but it throws the below error while passing the kill command:

sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Kindly advise..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot a space?

```
$next = shell_exec("kill -10 " . $pid2);
```

Comment: I wish! ha, I added the space and rid of the "" around the variable, here is what I got:

    sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected